# Joomla foreach AssocList - modify array

Tags: joomla-3.x, array

I have an associative array, where I need to modify 3 values before sending to the db.

Can somebody assist with the proper syntax for accomplishing this?

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows =$db->loadAssocList();   
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
 [$row['id']] . ' = ' . (int) ++$MaxID, [$row['id']];
 ...........
 ......
}
```

Here is the print out of the associative array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 11 [asset_id] => 671 [catid] => 102 [title] => Photo Master Copy [alias] => Photo Master Copy 692 [description] =>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax for modifying the array would be something like

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows =$db->loadAssocList();   
foreach ($rows as &$row)  // & to give a reference, not copy, to the row in rows
{
     ++$MaxID;
     $row['id']  =  $row['id'] + $MaxID;  // Add $MaxID to $row[id]
     .... // possibly other modifications?
}
```